# Terra equivalent for raster::stack()?

Tags: r, gis, raster, terra

Basically the title. I know you can read in a folder of rasters with rast() but I just want to stack two rasters that are read in separately. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

Note that with `raster::stack`, you were able to  use it either on multiple arguments (`stack(x1,x2,x3)`) or on a list (`stack(list(x1,x2, x3))`).

This is no longer true with terra's `c`. You need to differentiate:

- use `c(x1, x2, x3)` when providing separate arguments
- use `rast(list(x1,x2,x3))` when providing the arguments as a list.

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.5.21

x <- rast(xmin=-110, xmax=-80, ymin=40, ymax=70, ncols=30, nrows=30)
values(x) <- 1:ncell(x)

many_rasters <- list(x,x)

## this works
rast( many_rasters)
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 30, 30, 2  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#> extent      : -110, -80, 40, 70  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#> sources     : memory  
#>               memory  
#> names       : lyr.1, lyr.1 
#> min values  :     1,     1 
#> max values  :   900,   900

## just using c creates a list
c(many_rasters)
#> [[1]]
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 30, 30, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#> extent      : -110, -80, 40, 70  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#> source      : memory 
#> name        : lyr.1 
#> min value   :     1 
#> max value   :   900 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 30, 30, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#> extent      : -110, -80, 40, 70  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#> source      : memory 
#> name        : lyr.1 
#> min value   :     1 
#> max value   :   900
```

Comment: Using `do.call` is not a good approach here as you can do `rast( list(x1,x2,x3))  )`

Comment: thanks @RobertHijmans! I updated accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

For future users with this question note that `terra::c()` returns

> Error: 'c' is not an exported object from 'namespace:terra'

To stack rasters in `terra` you can simply use base `c()`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `terra::c()`. It combines `SpatRaster` objects, as long as they have the same extent and resolution.

Comment: this isn't correct. returns error