# Error "'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'" when using brick() function

Tags: r, raster

I have six raster bricks (I'm working with wildfire emissions data), and want to combine them into one RasterBrick object. When I try to stack the six objects and use the brick function, I get the following error:

`Error in matrix(unlist(ini), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) :  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL' In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)`

I tried just stacking two bricks (brick_1 and brick_2), and the brick() function seemed to work. However, when I added in the third brick, the error happened again, so it seems like something may be wrong with the format of some of the bricks.

The code I used to create and stack the bricks is below:

```
lng <- seq(from=-130, to=-110, by=res_xy)
lat <- seq(from=30, to=45, by=res_xy)


lng2 <- rep.int(lng, length(lat))
lat2 <- rep.int(lat, length(lng))
lat2 <- sort(lat2)
grd <- as.data.frame(cbind(lng2, lat2))
grd$PM25 <- 0 #no emissions by default

raster_cat <- list()
rdsChunk <- 60 #roughly two months

start_time <- Sys.time()
for (i in 1:365) {
  #for (i in 121:365) {
  print(paste('Processing days (total 365):', i))
  pm25_tmp <- subset(finn24_2018_pm25_cal2, DAY == i)[, c("LONGI", "LATI", "PM25")]
  
  if (nrow(pm25_tmp) == 0){#no emissions data for that day
    r <- rasterFromXYZ(grd, res = c(res_xy, res_xy), crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")    
  } else{
    # for each point in pm25_tmp, find the nearest neighbor from grd
    closest <- RANN::nn2(data = grd[, 1:2], query = pm25_tmp[, 1:2], k = 1)
    # argument k sets the number of nearest neighbours, here 1 (the closest)
    
    # Get coordinates of nearest neighbor
    pm25_tmp$lng2 <- grd[closest$nn.idx, "lng2"]
    pm25_tmp$lat2 <- grd[closest$nn.idx, "lat2"]
    
    # it might happen that multiple pm25_tmp records have a single grd record match
    pm25 <- ddply(pm25_tmp, .(lng2, lat2), summarise,
                  PM25=mean(PM25, na.rm=TRUE))
    grd_sub1 <- merge(pm25, grd[, 1:2], by=c("lng2", "lat2"), all.x=TRUE, all.y=FALSE)
    # use anti_join to find those ones that are in grd but not grid_sub1
    grd_sub2 <- anti_join(grd[,1:2], grd_sub1[, 1:2], by = NULL) # NULL indicates using all the columns
    grd_sub2$PM25 <- 0
    grd2 <- rbind(grd_sub1, grd_sub2)
    
    r <- rasterFromXYZ(grd2, res = c(res_xy, res_xy), crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
  } 
  
  raster_cat[[i]] <- r
  if(i==365){ # the last chunk of data with total records more than rdsChunk 
    file_name <- paste("PM25_2018Raster_Cal", i, ".grd", sep = "")
    raster_stack <- stack(lapply(((i%/%rdsChunk - 1) * rdsChunk + 1):i, function(i)  raster_cat[[i]])) #301-365, %/% and %% for quotient and remainder
    writeRaster(raster_stack, file = file.path(stilt_wd, "calsacto/data", file_name), format="raster", overwrite=TRUE)
  } else if ((i%%rdsChunk == 0) & ((365 - i )> rdsChunk)) { #i.e., not the last chunk yet
    file_name <- paste("PM25_2018Raster_Cal", i, ".grd", sep = "") #default raster format is grd
    raster_stack <- stack(lapply((i-rdsChunk+1):i, function(i)  raster_cat[[i]]))
    writeRaster(raster_stack, file = file.path(stilt_wd, "calsacto/data", file_name), format="raster", overwrite=TRUE)
    raster_cat <- list() #reset raster list
  }
}
end_time <- Sys.time()
print(paste("Total time spent: ", end_time-start_time, sep = ""))

#read one raster stack and convert it to raster brick
stack_1 <- file.path(stilt_wd, "calsacto/data", "PM25_2018Raster_Cal60.grd")
brick_1 <- brick(stack_1)
nlyrs_1 <- nlayers(brick_1)
nlyrs_1

stack_2 <- file.path(stilt_wd, "calsacto/data", "PM25_2018Raster_Cal120.grd")
brick_2 <- brick(stack_2)
nlyrs_2 <- nlayers(brick_2)
nlyrs_2

stack_3 <- file.path(stilt_wd, "calsacto/data", "PM25_2018Raster_Cal180.grd")
brick_3 <- brick(stack_3)
nlyrs_3 <- nlayers(brick_3)
nlyrs_3

stack_4 <- file.path(stilt_wd, "calsacto/data", "PM25_2018Raster_Cal240.grd")
brick_4 <- brick(stack_4)
nlyrs_4 <- nlayers(brick_4)
nlyrs_4

stack_5 <- file.path(stilt_wd, "calsacto/data", "PM25_2018Raster_Cal300.grd")
brick_5 <- brick(stack_5)
nlyrs_5 <- nlayers(brick_5)
nlyrs_5

stack_6 <- file.path(stilt_wd, "calsacto/data", "PM25_2018Raster_Cal365.grd")
brick_6 <- brick(stack_6)
nlyrs_6 <- nlayers(brick_6)
nlyrs_6

nlyrs <- nlyrs_1 + nlyrs_2 + nlyrs_3 + nlyrs_4 + nlyrs_5 + nlyrs_6
nlyrs

emi_stack_2018 <- stack(brick_1, brick_2, brick_3, brick_4, brick_5, brick_6)

emi_brick_2018 <- brick(emi_stack_2018)
```

I am new to working with raster data, so any suggestions are appreciated!!

Comment: You might find using [terra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71213802/terra-equivalent-for-rasterstack) more straight forward and `terra` is going to replace `raster` in the near future one thinks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was an R memory limitation - rebooting and clearing the workspace resolved the issue.